# Show that the following family of hash functions is $2$-wise independent but not $3$-wise independent

Tags: data-structures, probability-theory, hash, hash-tables

I've really been thinking about and working on this problem for a while, and I would appreciate if someone could offer any help towards the solution.

> Consider the following family of hash functions that map $w$-bit
>   numbers to $l$-bit numbers (i.e. the range is $\{0,...,m-1\}$ where
>    $m=2^l$):
>
> $\mathcal{H} = \{h_{A,b}|A\in \{0,1\}^{l\times w}, b \in
>  \{0,1\}^{l\times 1}\}$, where $h_{A,b}(x) = Ax+b\mod 2$
>
> Show that $\mathcal{H}$ is $2$-wise independent but not $3$-wise
>   independent ($\mathcal{H}$ is $k$-wise independent if for any $k$
>   inputs $x_1,...,x_k$ and hash values $v_1,...,v_k$,
>   $\Pr\limits_{h\in\mathcal{H}} \left( \bigwedge\limits_{1\le i\le k}
>  h(x_i)=v_i \right)=m^{-k} $).

I'm first trying to show that $\mathcal{H}$ is $2$-wise independent. So consider any two inputs $x_1, x_2$ and hash values $v_1,v_2$. Then it's required that $\Pr \left( h(x_1)=v_1 \wedge h(x_2)=v_2 \right)=\frac{1}{m^2}$.

$$\Pr \left( h(x_1)=v_1 \wedge h(x_2)=v_2\right)$$

$$\Rightarrow \Pr\left( Ax_1+b = v_1 \mod 2\wedge Ax_2+b=v_2 \mod 2\right)$$

What about this equation shows that the probability is $\frac{1}{m^2}$? If we were trying to show $3$-wise independence, we would have:

$$\Pr\left( Ax_1+b = v_1 \mod 2 \wedge Ax_2+b=v_2 \mod 2 \wedge Ax_3+b=v_3 \mod 2\right)$$

Why is this *not* $\frac{1}{m^3}$?

I just don't know how to evaluate an expression like $\Pr\left( Ax_1+b = v_1 \mod 2 \wedge Ax_2+b=v_2 \mod 2 \wedge Ax_3+b=v_3 \mod 2\right)$. I've tried searching online for similar problems, but none seem to help with solving this one specifically.

Comment: Can you show that the family is 1-wise independent? That would be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint for showing 2-wise independence:** Given $x_1,x_2$ and $v_1,v_2$, write the desired equations in a different way:
$$
b = v_1 - Ax_1, \\
A(x_2-x_1) = v_2 - v_1.
$$

**Regarding 3-wise independence:** I could be missing something, but it seems that the family *is* 3-wise independent.

**Hint for refuting 4-wise independence:** Take $x_3 = x_1 + x_2$ and $x_4 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I'm slightly confused though. For 2-wise independence, how does the fact that $A(x_2-x_1)=v_2-v_1$ help in determining the probability? Are we asking $\Pr[A(x_2-x_1)=v_2-v_1]$ now? If so, why is this equal to $\frac{1}{m^2}$?

Comment: Also, what makes you think that the family is 3-wise independent?

Comment: @Kelsey I'm giving hints, not providing a complete solution. For 2-wise independence, I suggest you focus on the special case $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = [1\;0\;\cdots\;0]$. Once you understand 2-wise independence, you can perhaps think about 3-wise independence.

Comment: So if $x_1 = \vec{0}$ and $x_2 = [1 0 ... 0]^T$, then we'd have $\Pr[b = v_1 \wedge a_1+b = v_2]$, where $a_1$ is the first column of $A$. I think my trouble is with evaluating these probabilities, in the case of $\Pr[b = v_1 \wedge a_1+b = v_2]$, how can we determine what this probability will equal?

Comment: @Kelsey Right, you have to figure out what this probability is. But you'll have to do it on your own. Try to use the chain rule: $\Pr[b=v_1 \land a_1+b=v_2] = \Pr[b=v_1] \cdot \Pr[a_1=v_2-b|b=v_1]$.

Comment: It seems like $\Pr[b=v_1]$ should just be $\frac{1}{m}$, since $v_1$ is arbitrarily taken from the range. Likewise, $\Pr[a_1=v_2-b:b=v_1]$ should also be $\frac{1}{m}$, since $v_2$ and $v_1$ are arbitrarily taken from the range as well.

Comment: Right, since $b$ and $a_1$ are chosen uniformly at random, they equal any given value with probability $1/m$. Now try to generalize this to general $x_1,x_2$. Give it a couple of hours before asking for further help.

Comment: Awesome. I think I understand the $2$-wise independence now. For $3$-wise independence, I find the same two equations for $2$-wise, but the third equation $Ax_3+b=v_3\Rightarrow -A(x_3-x_1)-v_1 = v_3$, so we can fully determine $v_3$ from $v_1,x_1,x_3$. Is that why this suggests that the family is not $3$-wise independent? What was the basis for your initial inclination that it was?

Comment: The problem with this argument is that you don't actually know $A$.

Comment: But you do know that it is a fixed matrix. Does this matter at all?

Comment: You haven't explained how to determine $v_3$ from $v_1,x_1,x_3$. Your explanation includes $A$, which isn't part of the "input".

Comment: Can you explain the $4$-wise (non)independence then? By your hint, I get: $$\Pr[Ax_1+b=v_1\wedge Ax_2+b=v_2\wedge A(x_1+x_2)+b=v_3\wedge b = v_4]$$

We know that $\Pr[Ax_1+v_4=v_1]\cdot \Pr[Ax_2+v_4=v_2]\cdot \Pr[b=v_4] = \frac{1}{m^3}$, so why is it that $\Pr[A(x_1+x_2)+v_4=v_3] \not = \frac{1}{m}$? Is it because $A(x_1+x_2)+2v_4=v_1+v_2$, so that $v_3$ fully determined by $Ax_1+b=v_1$ and $Ax_2+b=v_2$?

Comment: The most succinct way to state it is that $v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4=0$.

Comment: How could you show the family is not $4$-wise independent without coming up with a concrete (counter)example like that? For example, how could you conclude the same thing if you just had $\Pr[Ax_1+b=v_1\wedge Ax_2+b=v_2\wedge Ax_3+b=v_3\wedge Ax_4+b=v_4]$? I'm just trying to find a clear way to show something is $k$-wise independent or isn't $k$-wise independent, for some $k$.

Comment: There are no tricks. Each case has its own solution. In this case, the simplest solution is to find a linear dependency among the outputs.